# Can you comment on this helper class to handle OnDestory logic?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Destroying components again and again is annoying to recode so why not create a extendable class to take care of the logic such as managing a Subject and some easy pipe handlers. There might be times when you can't use this helper class in certain scenarios, but for general scenarios it seems like a huge time saver.

Please see the full working example below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-fb2u4z?file=app%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.ts

Comment: If you want this logic you can take a look at 
take-until-ng-destroy: https://www.npmjs.com/package/take-until-ng-destroy

As for you question, I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you ran the full example you would understand that the package you suggested achieves the same functionality.This idea is exactly what I was looking for, Thank you. Here is more popular package that does the same thing - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-take-until-destroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ngx-take-until-destroy** is the elegant way to achieve it!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-take-until-destroy

```
import { untilDestroyed } from 'ngx-take-until-destroy';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inbox',
  templateUrl: './inbox.component.html',
})
export class InboxComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  ngOnInit() {
    interval(1000)
      .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
      .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
  }

  // This method must be present, even if empty.
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // To protect you, we'll throw an error if it doesn't exist.
  }
}
```